# Smarty: string variable contains brackets

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I have an associative array assigned to a Smarty variable, something like this:

```
$foo = array('my[content][hello]' => 'hello', 'my[content][goodbye]' => 'goodbye', ...
```

In the template file, how do I access `hello`? This fails:

```
{$foo.my[content][hello]}
```

My guess it that is fails because the brackets means I'm trying to access parts of an array. In this case, I'm not. The brackets are just part of the variable name. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
{$foo.{'my[content][hello]'}}
```

or

```
{$foo['my[content][hello]']}
```

or (if all else fails [meaning you're still on Smarty2]):

```
{assign var=key value='my[content][hello]'}
{$foo.$key}
```